# Query SEPA server for river data

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, getfeatureinfo, scotland

The Scottish Environmental Protection Agency has an ARCGis server with river data I'd like to query.

https://map.environment.gov.scot/sewebmap/?layers=riverClass

At this URL it shows what I want to get

http://map.sepa.org.uk/arcgis/services/WMS_Hydrography/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&CRS=EPSG:27700&SRS=EPSG:27700&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&BBOX=300433.7197776127,664736.2187099421,330675.3812723706,677830.5463674661&WIDTH=1067&HEIGHT=462&LAYERS=9&QUERY_LAYERS=9&X=527&Y=&I=527&J=108&FEATURE_COUNT=50&EXCEPTION=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&SERVICENAME=

I'm after finding the river classification at a given Longitude and Latitude.

The above URL uses British National Grid but I have only a Long and Lat.  I think that means settings sr=3395

I'm wanting to get the river classification data in JSON for my PHP website.  I've worked out this URL but it just says No Results Found.

http://map.sepa.org.uk/ArcGIS/rest/services/WMS_Hydrography/MapServer/identify?geometry=57.0759,-4.84497&layers=all&tolerance=2&sr=3395&mapExtent=57,-4,58,-3&imageDisplay=1056,816,96

What am I doing wrong in the above URL?

Comment: try http://map.sepa.org.uk/arcgis/rest/services/WMS_Hydrography/MapServer/identify?geometry=429157%2C623009&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=27700&layers=all&layerDefs=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&tolerance=2&mapExtent=57%2C-4%2C58%2C-3&imageDisplay=1056%2C816%2C96&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&dynamicLayers=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnUnformattedValues=false&returnFieldName=false&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=&mapRangeValues=&layerRangeValues=&f=pjson

Answer (score 0):

http://map.sepa.org.uk/arcgis/rest/services/WMS_Hydrography/MapServer/identify?geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&sr=4326&layers=all%3A4&layerDefs=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&tolerance=2&mapExtent=57%2C-4%2C58%2C-3&imageDisplay=1056%2C816%2C96&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&dynamicLayers=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnUnformattedValues=false&returnFieldName=false&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=&mapRangeValues=&layerRangeValues=&f=pjson&geometry=-4.84497,57.0759

This works

The geometry argument is the longitude,latitude which is unusual

And the projection I want seems to be sr=4326